# Need a little help integrating JAXRSClientFactory with OpenAM RESTful service

Tags: json, rest, tomcat7, cxf, openam

I admit I'm a greenhorn with web services.

I am attempting to call an OpenAM restful web service from a legacy unprotected tomEE+ servlet. My problem is that I don't understand what I should be creating for the second argument of:

```
JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://openam.mylocalAMserver.lan:8080/openam/json/authenticate", WhatClassGoesHere.class);
```

The OpenAM [documentation](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-rest.html#rest-api-auth-json) provides this:

> 3.3.1. Authentication & Logout
>
> $ curl --request POST  --header "X-OpenAM-Username: demo" --header
>   "X-OpenAM-Password: changeit"  --header "Content-Type:
>   application/json" --data "{}" 
>   https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/json/authenticate
>
> { "tokenId": "AQIC5w...NTcy*", "successUrl": "/openam/console" }

Should I create a class with instance variables "tokenId", "successURL" and passing that as the second parameter to JAXRSClientFactory? Do I need to worry about all of the parameters specified? Once I figure this out, I've got to figure out how to actually pass the user name and password and invoke the service...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a JAXRS question, and is not specific to OpenAM.  You need to write Java code to make requests and parse the JSON response. JAXRS is one way to do this- but there are others as well.

Look for a good JAXRS tutorial. The OpenAM part is very simple once you understand REST web services.

Comment: Thanks. Now if I could just find a Tutorial that works against the version of CXF found within TomEE+ 1.5.2. Which is CXF 2.6.4 which does NOT implement JAX-RS 2.0. I keep finding tutorials for JAX-RS 2.0 and its cool new client features... If you know of one send it my way please. Thanks.